# What's the meaning of 'an idea of' here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> It’s hard to show the results of this without exposing sensitive data, so here’s just an idea of what you might see in your access logs.

I read it from [here](http://buer.haus/2017/06/29/escalating-xss-in-phantomjs-image-rendering-to-ssrflocal-file-read/) but confused with the word 'idea', therefore I tried search [idea](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/idea) in cambridge dictionary online and [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=idea+meaning&oq=idea+meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65j69i60j35i39j0l2.4207j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Finally after searching 'idea' here and no satisfied meaning, I have to come for help. If anything is off topic, I will close the question. Hope your help sincerely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly a simpler answer that might help inexperienced English speakers would be: "example".

**idea of = example.**

So you might have this quote instead.....

> It’s hard to show the results of this without exposing sensitive data, so here’s just an <strike>idea</strike> example of what you might see in your access logs.

Comment: Thank u. Can u tell me how u get this explanation? Why do I try search online and get nothing about 'idea of = example'. Is there any problem with my search technique or something others?

Comment: I see where you are having trouble. You can't just Google it. This is really more of an idiom used in English. Idea in the context it was used means, "concept" or "mental impression". You can look that one up. A concept in this sense, or an impression, is a type of visualization. An example is a sample or illustration or visual aid (visualization). They are very similar when used in this way. "Idea of" has come to mean, basically: "concept", "example", "visualization", "sample", etc... Does this help?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. How can I find the idiom of the word 'idea' when I have the same problem? Can you give me some advice to solve this kind situation by self with internet.

Answer (score 2):

It means the main abstraction of the results excluding sensitive details, i.e. the important points.

From  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idea):

> :  the central meaning or chief end of a particular action or situation

Another good synonym is 'gist,' which means 'the substance or essence.'  In other words, they're not giving you all the specific details.  They're just giving you the important points you need to know.

> It’s hard to show the results of this without exposing sensitive data, so here’s the gist of what you might see...

Answer (score 2):

**idea (of sth)**: an impression of what something is like.

So, you may read the sentence something like this:

> ...here is an impression of  what you might see in your access logs.